# Como criar uma aplicativo de chat com o Firebase e Android?

Tags: android, firebase, chat

Quero criar um chat com Android e Firebase, todos os tutoriais que vi na internet não são completos.

Gostaria de saber como que faz um chat usando essas duas ferramentas.  Não precisa ficar como o Whatsapp, mas que consiga atingir o objetivo de enviar e receber mensagens.

Comment: Você pode tirar a base de um exemplo que o pessoal do Firebase fez [git exemplo](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/tree/master/android/app).

Comment: valeu Jefferson..

Comment: https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352?product=5483321653723136&_ga=1.33938472.843565695.1438022865%3Futm_source%3Dblog&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=sb_widget_enroll

Comment: quando iniciei os estudos com firebase o curso acima me ajudou muito, e no curso é criado uma aplicação de chat, o curso esta em inglês vc terá que usar a tradução automática do youtube que não é 100%, mas ajuda mt, ainda mais pelo fato de ter sido desenvolvido em parceria com a google

Comment: valeu Vitor, vou dar uma olhada no curso

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro passo é [configurar um aplicativo cliente do Firebase Cloud Messaging no Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=pt-br). Depois você pode iniciar usando o [**FriendlyChat**](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat). Ele inclui versões iniciais e finais do código para Web, [**Android**](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/tree/master/android), Objective-C e Swift. Para começar, veja os links abaixo para instruções do codelab das seguintes plataformas:

- [Web Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/)
- [Android Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/)
- [Swift Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/)
- [Objective-C Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-objc/)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou começar a dar uma estudada no assunto...valeu....

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem vários exemplos.

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=chat+firebases

inclusive o oficial do firebases